# How can I achieve a centered FlowArrangement in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, swing, charts, jfreechart

Within the `XYPlot` legend of a chart created with `JFreeChart`, I would like items to be arranged with a `FlowLayout` arrangement such that excessively long lines are automatically wrapped, however I cannot seem to figure out how to have it so that the items are also center-aligned relative to the entire legend. In other words, I would like line wrapping to remain, but I would like the newly wrapped line to have a `HorizontalAlignment.CENTER` as opposed to a `HorizontalAlignment.LEFT`.

None of the methods I have yet found in the API or source will allow me to effectively have a centered `FlowArrangement`. Is there a convenient way to do this or can I expect to write my own custom `Arrangement` based on `FlowArrangement` but centered?

The following code snippet is what I had assumed would work, though does not seem to be having any effect on the legend.

```
LegendTitle chartLegend = chart.getLegend();
chartLegend.setLegendItemGraphicEdge(RectangleEdge.TOP);
chartLegend.getItemContainer().setArrangement(new FlowArrangement(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0, 0));
```

**EDIT:** Another requirement is that the entire graph (with the legend) has to be easily printable, and thus all should be on the same `ChartPanel`, and thus I don't see using more than one separate `JPanel` as an option.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen two general approaches:

1. Remove the legend created by your chosen `ChartFactory` and create a new one having the desired parameters, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22248287/230513).
2. Render the legend items in a separate `Container` having the desired layout, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309587/230513).

   ```
   JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
   ```

Comment: I have seen the example linked in the first possibility but it did not work as-expected when I tried it. Each element of the legend ended up aligned to its own arbitrary axis. As for the second option, what I failed to mention is that I need the entire thing (with the legend) to be printable, so every element has to be on the same `ChartPanel`. I have edited my question to reflect this requirement.

Comment: Maybe try `GridArrangement`?